# Select with datetime from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php-5.3

I have a problem with my select : 
I have a form with 2 text boxes : 
date_min and date_max. This dates come in controller :

```
2015-05-15
```

Now in database my dates : c_win like this :

```
2015-08-20 21:20:20
```

In the query I do :

```
if ($date_min != '' && $date_max != ''){
        $aFilter = ' AND c_win > '.$date_min.' AND c_ig.date_gain < '.$date_max;
    }
```

But I think I need to reface the dates. Help me please!! Thx in advance

Comment: dates must be quotes while using in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around your dates

```
$aFilter = ' AND c_win > "'.$date_min.'" AND c_ig.date_gain < "'.$date_max.'"';
```

Comment: Again this wraps the column in a date function rendering any index unusable.. same reason I downvoted the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

change the query like

```
 $aFilter = ' AND date(c_win) > '.$date_min.' AND date(c_ig.date_gain) < '.$date_max;
```

date function return only date like '2015-08-20' from '2015-08-20 21:20:20'

i hope this is working for you.

Comment: And you've just ruined any index on `c_win` or `date_gain` while not actually fixing the issue.

Comment: I have mutiple dates in database like this : 
`2015-01-20 21:20:20`
`2015-01-20 21:20:20`
But with my query I got null :
`AND DATE(c_ig.date_gain) > 2008-05-13 
                    AND DATE(c_ig.date_gain) < 2015-05-05`

Comment: Why I have this situation?

Comment: 2015-01-20 21:20:20 date is not between 2008-05-13 to 2015-05-05 this range so for that you got a null result.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DATE()`:

```
if ($date_min != '' && $date_max != ''){
    $aFilter = ' AND DATE(c_win) > "' . $date_min . '" AND DATE(c_ig.date_gain) < "' . $date_max . '"';
}
```

Comment: Why -1?! I was just 50 seconds after renishkhunt :]

Comment: Because MySQL can't use an index on `c_win` or `c_ig.date_gain` with this query

Comment: How do you know that there was an index on this field? Question was about getting correct results not regarding performance issue...

Comment: I don't, but a query which allows the index to be used is just as simple.. so I can't recommend this. A consistent approach to date-based comparison is preferable.

Comment: I agree that using `DATE()` can't use index because only operators like `>` cast to `DATETIME`. If you're using index (you should ;)) avoid using `DATE()`. If not and just want a quick solution then `DATE()` will help

Comment: I would agree, but the fact that a query can be written with ease that, in my opinion, is more readable and which does not have this issue is my reason for the downvote.. not that it won't work.

Comment: I understand but imho if something is working shouldn't be downvoted like it wouldn't work. You have a better solution? Go for it, don't upvote, don't downvote :) That's just my opinion

Comment: Because it's a dangerous answer.. it's actually worse than an incorrect answer. I spent a whole day on a slow code base correcting this exact issue which could have been avoided easily. I don't want anyone else having the same problem because someone read your solution first.

Answer (score 1):

Don't wrap the column in `DATE()` as the optimizer can't use an index on the column.. plus I'd be binding in variables using PDO or mysqli rather than concatting them..

When I have date comparisons in my code with date inputs, I almost always use:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM table t
 WHERE t.time >= :min_date
   AND t.time <  :max_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Which exactly covers all the times between the dates without breaking the index.
It also assumes that the dates provided are inclusive.. which is logical for a UI.

In your case this would be:

```
$aFilter = ' AND c_win >= "'.$date_min.'" AND c_ig.date_gain < "'.$date_max.'" + INTERVAL 1 DAY';
```

**BONUS INFO**

If you are wondering why your query ran but didn't give the correct results..

```
AND c.win > 2008-05-13 AND c_ig.date_gain < 2015-05-05
```

without quotes evaluates as integers to:

```
AND c.win > 1990 AND c_ig.date_gain < 2005
```

Which is then implicitly converted to:

```
AND c.win > "1990-01-01 00:00:00" AND c_ig.date_gain < "2005-01-01 00:00:00"
```

Another good reason not to concatenate query strings.

Comment: plus1, but my advice: don't use `SELECT *` if you don't need it ;)